# Question about placing fragments in nav-graph when using navigation component?

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

Assume there are 3 tabs in bottomnavview, named as Home, Popular and User. There are 3 nav-graphs as I use NavigationExtensions from advanced navigation sample.

And there are another four fragments as List1, Detail1, List2, Detail2.

The problem is I need to navigate to List1 from both home and popular tabs, and Detail1 from home, popular, List1 and Detail2 also. The same goes to List2 and Detail2 fragments.

What I have tried.

Because of different nav-graphs I placed the four fragments in both home and popular nav-graph, That didn't worked well. And also I tried to create nav-graph for each of the four fragment and nesting the graph in every other graph. Later I stopped doing that because that would be a tedious task to manage every nav-graph if I create more fragments in future..

Any solutions or workarounds for this problem?